# Install libGL.so.1 on Puppy Linux

Tags: opengl, puppylinux

I need to install libGL.so.1 as shared library, but I'm confused about package to [download](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libGL.so.1&submit=Search%20...&system=&arch=).

What should I look to download the right one, the graphic card vendor (I've got Nvidia)?
Maybe I should install Mesa OpenGL?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the proprietary nVidia drivers, they should have included their own version of libGL. For the open-source `nouveau` driver, use Mesa's libGL implementation.